# How select filtered result from search in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a form where one of the input is a search bar to filter data from API. I want to select a desired result to be the selected item for the input and attached to the formData.
Here's what I have tried:

```
const Referral = () => {
 

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [searchTitle, setSearchTitle] = useState("");

  ///////////////////////////search filter/////////////////////////

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadPosts = async () => {
      const response = await Axios.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
      );
      setPosts(response.data);
    };

    loadPosts();
  }, []);

  //////////////////////////search filter end //////////////////

 
  return (
    <div className="mx-auto" align="center">
    

      <form
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
      >
       
        <div className="bg-gray-200 my-2">
          <h3>
            My Form
            </h3>
        </div>

        <label>
          <span>
            Encounter Code{" "}
          </span>
          <input
            required
            placeholder="Enter Encounter Code"
            type="text"
          />
        </label>
       

        <label>
          <span>
            Destination Facility{" "}
          </span>
          <input
            placeholder="Search Facility Name..."
            type="search"
            onChange={(e) => setSearchTitle(e.target.value)}
          />
          {searchTitle &&
            posts
              .filter((value) =>
                value.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTitle.toLowerCase())
              )
              .map((item) => (
                <h5 className="cursor-pointer" key={item.id}>
                  {item.title}
                </h5>
              ))}
        </label>
        
        <Button
          fullWidth
          type="submit"
        >
         Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Referral;
```

I remove a lot of code for brevity. so onClick on a result from search, it selected result should come up in the search input and subsequently added to formData. I need help at this point.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question clearly. So what you're trying to do is, when a user selects a particular result you returned, you want to set its title as the search text?

Comment: @Karthik Sivasubramaniam  Exactly

Comment: Then try adding an `onClick` attribute to your mapped `h5` element, like so: `<h5 onClick={() => setSearchTitle(item.title)} >`. I'm not sure what use case you're after, but this should give you what you want.